# Запуск главного потока

Tags: c#

Как запустить метод в главном потоке, и метод во вторичном потоке?

Comment: Главный поток создаётся при старте процесса, в Windows точно так, как в других ОС не буду утверждать, запуск метода без явного вызова метода - это что?

Могу предложить [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) и перевод [Работа с потоками в C#](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml).

Comment: не простой вызов метода(я знаю что он сразу будет являться главным)
а при помощи класса Thread который и должен его сделать главным

Comment: Главный - это тот, кто запускается первым. Он может запуститься, запустить остальных и сам завершиться...

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы вызываете метод, не создавая явно потоков, он выполняется в потоке, обрабатывающем  события пользовательского интерфейса. Для вызова дополнительного потока можно использовать BackgroundWorker. Пример:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundworker = new BackgroundWorker();

backgroundworker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // TODO: Выполнить нужный код
});

backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: backgroundworker.DoWork += {o,e}=>{// TODO: Выполнить нужный код};

Comment: @Spectre На вкус и цвет, кстати говоря :)

Comment: ИМХО, код представленный @Василий избыточен, для небольших операций - лямбда-синтаксис, для больших(более 3-х строк) именованный метод

Comment: @Spectre Сам придерживаюсь аналогичного вашему мнения, но просто существуют `coding standard'ы`, в которых использование лямбда-функций вообще запрещено :)

Comment: не знал о таком, а чем вызван этот запрет?